# Image is not moving away from cursor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a image ,i want whenever cursor try to touch  the image it moves away randomly  from the cursor i tried using jquery but it not working , see this link http://jsfiddle.net/emreerkan/atNva/

my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/569986/pexels-photo-569986.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600" width="100" height="100" alt="Grey Square" class="som" />
    
    
</body>
<!-- <script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script>
    alert('hi')
    jQuery(function($) {
    $('.som').mouseover(function() {
        var dWidth = $(document).width() - 100, // 100 = image width
            dHeight = $(document).height() - 100, // 100 = image height
            nextX = Math.floor(Math.random() * dWidth),
            nextY = Math.floor(Math.random() * dHeight);
        $(this).animate({ left: nextX + 'px', top: nextY + 'px' });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

my style.css

```
body { position: relative; }
#img { position: relative; }
```

Comment: It looks like it's working. What's the problem?

Comment: not working in chrome i tried

Comment: The `img` tag in your code above does not have `id="img"`. It has `class="som"`

Comment: working perfectly in chrome too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in css
use the pointer `.som` instead of `#img`
because in your `jQuey code` you used `top` and `left`,these properties will not work unless the position property is set first, in this case its `position:relative;`

(`static` is the default value of `position` )
everything else looks good